# How to Auto Update a Timestamp on Upsert in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, mongoose, upsert

If I have a Schema with the key `expires`; how could I get the value of that key to update automatically each time the document is updated? This might be more complicated, but, I am `upsert`ing so this value would need to be set on the initial `insert` and then updated on each `upsert`.

So, when the document is `insert`ed:

```
{
  expires: *an hour from the insert*
}
```

and when it's `update`d (via `upsert`):

```
{
  expires: *an hour from the update*
}
```

I'm using Mongoose if that has this functionality built in. If Mongodb does not support it nor does Mongoose I'll just have to work out the `expires:` and update the value but it would be nice to have this done automagically in Mongodb!

In fact, it would not den *really* need to work on the `insert`; as I could check if the `expires` was empty and extract the time from the `_id`.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose middleware doesn't fire on `update` calls, so you'd need to do it yourself:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 1);
MyModel.update({...}, {$set: {expires: expires, ...}}, {upsert: true}, callback);
```

Also, I don't know your use case, but you should also look at Mongo's built-in support for expiring data from collections if that's what you're trying to do.  See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

Comment: That might be a great idea actually; I need to know when an OAuth token expires (which is one hour in my case). Could I expire (TTL?) just the value of the access_token? Then if a _id exists and so too does the refresh_token, but the access_token has expired then I would know to request a new access_token?

Comment: @JonathonOates I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but MongoDB's expiration occurs at the document level, not individual fields.

Comment: I'll have to update it myself. I was hoping I could just expire the value of a particular key.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Mongoose allow passing `{ timestamps: true }` as an option when creating new models.  This feature will automatically set `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.  [Here is the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps).